# How to add a refresh button to dynamically update data from Database in MaterialUI Datagrid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am a new beginner in JS. Essentially the gist of the issue is this:

- I have a MySQL database from where I am loading my table data through Axios
- There are CRUD operations in my web app, which updates my DB anytime a request is made
- All the functions work and the changes get reflected in the backend, but not on the Datagrid unless I do a hard window reload
- I want to have a refresh button, which when clicked gets the new data from my database with no hard reload

I know it might be possible through a combination of setState variables and useEffect but all my attempts throughout the weekend have failed so far.
Any idea how to integrate them together?

data.js

```
import axios from "axios";
export const getData = async () => {
    let response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/h2h-backend/list');

    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
}
```

Datagrid

```
import { getData } from '../services/data';

export default function DataTable() {
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = React.useState(10);
  
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  useEffect(async () => {
    setData(await getData());
  }, [])

  let rows = searchInput
      ? data.filter((item) => item.cust_number.toString().match(new RegExp("^" + 
     searchInput, "gi")))
      : data;

    return (
      <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <DataGrid
            rows={rows}
            columns={columns}
            autoHeight={true}
            density='compact'
            rowHeight={40}
        />
    )
```

refreshbutton.js

```
export default function RefreshButton() {
    return (
        <Grid item xs={0.5} backgroundColor="rgba(39,61,74,255)" >
            <IconButton 
            aria-label="refresh" 
            size="small" 
            sx={iconSx}
            onClick={() => {
                window.location.reload();
            }}
            >
                <RefreshIcon sx={{fontSize: "18px"}}/>
            </IconButton>
        </Grid>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on how you are using the `useEffect` method in your `DataTable` component.

**This is a NO NO**

```
 useEffect(async () => {
    setData(await getData());
  }, [])
```

**Why?**

> `useEffect` is supposed to
> be a function that returns either nothing or a function.
> But an async function returns a Promise,
> which can't be called as a function! It's simply not what the
> useEffect hook expects for its first argument.

**This should work**

```
useEffect(() => {
  getData()
}, [])
```

[For more info](https://devtrium.com/posts/async-functions-useeffect)

With axios you have the alternative of doing a synchronous function without the async/await. Like so:

```
import axios from "axios"

export function getData(){
  let url = 'http://localhost:8080/h2h-backend/list'
  let dataFetched = undefined

  axios.get(url)
    .then((resp) => dataFetched = resp.data)
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
      
  return dataFetched
}
```

Comment: When I add your suggestions, I just get a blank screen

Comment: Try filtering the data inside the `getData` function after reciving the response

Comment: got it working through a conditional state variable inside useEffect, no further filters needed